# Prove that if $p > 1$, then $V$ is dense in $l^p$

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

In the space $l^p$ with $1 ≤ p < ∞$ we consider the following subset:

$V = ${${(x_1,x_2,x_3,...) \in l^p : \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}x_n = 0$}

I have to prove that if $p > 1$, then $V$ is dense in $l^p$ and if $p = 1$, then $V$ is not dense in $l^p$.

I know that if we let $X$ be a metric space, the subset $V \subset X$ is called dense when the closure of $V$ equals $X$, thus when $\overline{V} = X$.

For the first statement, the textbook states that we can use the following: Let $e_k = (0, . . . , 0, 1, 0, . . .)$, where the $1$ is at the k-th entry, and show that $e_k ∈ V$  $\forall k ∈ \mathbb{N}$.

I am not sure how to use the hint given by the textbook. Any help would be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think $e_k \notin V$.

Comment: @TimurBakiev It's very easy to show $e_k\in \overline V$.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich Sure. Actually, I was pointing on the obvious mistake in the question :)

Answer (score 2):

Fix $k$. Define $$v_n=e_k-\frac1n\sum_{j=1}^n e_j.$$ Show that $v_n\in V$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}||e_k-v_n||_p=0$. Hence $e_k\in\overline V$.